# What is this red component?

Tags: identification, components

What is this component? It has no part number, only specs written on it. It think it says "Bold" as a brand, but I'm not sure. What function does it perform?

The board is an Arçelik washing machine controller board. I added some more pictures if you want to take a crack at reversing it or need better detail. I've been trying to reverse the tacho circit unsuccessfully. KN5 must be the mains-in if I;m not mistaken.

[image]

Some extra photos:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/187ksNwLxfAj0S04dKREjdiFHQAki8Qkd?usp=sharing

Comment: Please put a photo showing the specs (and, if possible, surrounding components) clearly. And also, the info of what the circuit is (i.e. hoover controller) or where/what the circuit is taken from could be useful.

Comment: I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the heater relay. As discussed in this article https://howtofixit.net/samsung-dryer-not-heating/

Comment: Makes sense, but as you can see in the drive link, it connects to the board with 8 different pins. Isn't it a bit excessive?

Comment: It has to stay attached to the board when someone pulls the Fast-On terminals off with pliers... that big bulky body means a lot of leverage on the pins.

Comment: Most of them are connected to sth. tho

Comment: It's cheaper to add several pins to an existing bit of metal inside the relay. Adding another piece of metal just to add pins would cost extra.